# Given only the full path to a .class file, how can I load its Class object?

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

I'm working on an application that needs to be able to do some analysis on Java code; some through the text and some through reflection. The user should be able to input a directory and the program will pull all .java and .class files from it. I have no problem with the .java files but when I try getting the class of the .class file it doesn't work.

I've looked at using ClassLoader with URL. What I've been able to find so far has given me this

```
URL url = this.openFile().toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls = cl.loadClass(this.path);
return cls;
```

`path` is just a string containing the actual path of the .class file in question, e.g. `Users/me/Documents/Application/out/production/MyPackage/MyClass.class`. From what I understand from my own reading, this method ties me to knowing the package structure of the input, but in general I don't. All I have is the absolute path of the .class file. Is there a way, just using this path (or some simple transformation of it) that I can load into my program the actual MyClass class object and start doing reflection on it?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Use a byte code library to first read the file, so you can find out what the actual class name is.

   E.g. in your example it is probably `MyPackage.MyClass`, but you can't know that from the fully qualified file name.
2. Implement your own `ClassLoader` subclass, and call [`defineClass(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-byte:A-int-int-).

Recommend using option 2.